# Node name limitations in zookeeper

Tags: apache-zookeeper

Is there any documentation on the limitations on zookeeper node names? I can't find anything in official documentation regarding it. In particular, I want to know:

1. What characters are allowed?
2. Can I use any character from UTF-8 (like japanese characters)?
3. What is the maximum limit of characters/bytes (if any) for node name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**For 1, 2**: [Any unicode character can be used in a path subject to the following constraints](http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/current/zookeeperProgrammers.html#ch_zkDataModel):

- The null character (`\u0000`) cannot be part of a path name. (This causes problems with the C binding.)
- The following characters can't be used because they don't display well, or render in confusing ways: `\u0001 - \u001F` and `\u007F - \u009F`.
- The following characters are not allowed: `\ud800 - uF8FF`, `\uFFF0 - uFFFF`.
- The `.` character can be used as part of another name, but `.` and `..` cannot alone be used to indicate a node along a path, because ZooKeeper doesn't use relative paths. The following would be invalid: `/a/b/./c` or `/a/b/../c`.
- The token `zookeeper` is reserved.

PS: The source code: [PathUtils.validatePath()](https://github.com/apache/zookeeper/blob/master/zookeeper-server/src/main/java/org/apache/zookeeper/common/PathUtils.java#L43)

**For 3**: In fact, there is no limit on the length of name in ZK itself, but is is recommended not using too large name (e.g., ZK store entire data in memory for efficiency)

Comment: Hi from the future. I don't know if you're still around but I wanted to tell you I think this is a perfect answer. I was looking for Zookeeper node name limits, and this presents everything succinctly, and with a primary-source link to boot. Thanks!